# parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded to json

Tags: python

У amocrm есть возможность настроить webhooks
https://www.amocrm.ru/developers/content/digital_pipeline/webhooks

Столкнулся с проблемой.
amocrm отправляет не json, а `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Пример запроса

```
curl -X 'POST' 'ссылка на нашу url' -H 'connection: close' -H 'x-forwarded-for: 88.212.249.20' -H 'content-length: 1576' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'user-agent: amoCRM-WebHook-client/2.0' -H 'host: webhook.site' -d $'contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=2289365&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bresponsible_user_id%5D=3876319&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bdate_create%5D=1571496221&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Blast_modified%5D=1571499023&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_user_id%5D=3876319&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bmodified_user_id%5D=3876319&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=101163&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=dfgdfs&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcode%5D=POSITION&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=101165&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%2B72209211333&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Benum%5D=150989&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bcode%5D=PHONE&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bold_responsible_user_id%5D=3876319&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_at%5D=1571496221&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Bupdated_at%5D=1571499023&contacts%5Bupdate%5D%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=contact&account%5Bsubdomain%5D=waxijocod&account%5Bid%5D=28666972&account%5B_links%5D%5Bself%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fwaxijocod.amocrm.ru'
```

Вопрос, как в python , средствами flask или bottle распарсить получаемые данные в json? А именно получить на выходе

contacts

```
{
 "add":[{
         "id":"2299207",
         "name":"test",
         "responsible_user_id":"3876319",
         "date_create":"1571413620",
         "last_modified":"1571500037",
         "created_user_id":"3876319",
         "modified_user_id":"3876319",
         "company_name":"test",
         "linked_company_id":"2299205",
         "created_at":"1571413620",
         "updated_at":"1571500037",
         "type":"contact"}]
}
```

account

```
{
  "subdomain": "waxijocod",
  "id": "28666972",
  "_links": {"self":"https://waxijocod.amocrm.ru"}
}
```

Comment: Weebhooks настраивал по этому мануалу - https://www.amocrm.ru/developers/content/api/webhooks-2

Comment: Flask делает это автоматически и предоставляет данные в `request.form`, Bottle тоже через `request.forms`. Или вам этого мало и вы хотите распарсить это всё тщательнее?

Comment: С помощью flask я могу получить только объект - ImmutableMultiDict([('contacts[update][0][custom_fields][1][code]', 'PHONE'), ('contacts[update][0][old_responsible_user_id]', '3876319'), ('contacts[update][0][type]', 'contact'), ('contacts[update][0][last_modified]', '1571499023').... , т.е. в качестве ключей используются такие значения 'contacts[update][0][custom_fields][1][code]', хотелось бы как в примере, в виде json

Comment: Если более подробно, то form.data.to_dict() - дает на выходе {'contacts[update][0][name]': 'Имя не указано', 'contacts[update][0][created_at]': '1571496221', 'contacts[update][0][custom_fields][1][values][0][enum]': '150989',.........

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашел тут
https://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.parse-str/

```
def php_parse_str(query_string, unquote=True):
def recurse( pair, out=None, indent=0 ):
    if isinstance(pair,dict):
        (k, v) = pair.popitem()
        if out is None:
            if isinstance(k,int) or k == '':
                out = []
            else:
                out = OrderedDict()
        if isinstance(out,list) and (k == ''):
            out.append( recurse(v,indent=indent+1) )
        elif isinstance(out,list) and (k != ''):
            out = dict(enumerate(out)) # merge list with dict
            out[k] = recurse(v, out.get(k),indent=indent+1)
        elif isinstance(out,dict) and k == '':
            numeric_indices = [k for k in out.keys() if isinstance(k,int)]
            out[1+max(numeric_indices) if numeric_indices else 0] = recurse(v, out.get(k))
        elif isinstance(out,dict):
            out[k] = recurse(v, out.get(k),indent=indent+1)
        else:
            return recurse({k:v},indent=indent+1) # overwriting scalar out by dict or list
        return out
    return pair

plist = []
if query_string == "":
    return mydict
for element in query_string.split("&"):
    try:
        if unquote:
            (var, val) = element.split("=")
            var = urllib.unquote_plus(var)
            val = urllib.unquote_plus(val)
        else:
            (var, val) = element.split("=")
    except ValueError:
        raise MalformedQueryStringError
    plist.append(parser_helper(var, val))

out = OrderedDict()
for pair in plist:
    out = recurse(pair,out)
return out
```

Строки, получения даных и преобразования в dict - с котором мы позже можем работать.

```
raw_data = request.get_data().decode("utf-8")
data = unquote(raw_data)
order_dict_data = php_parse_str(data)
```

В php все проще

```
<?php
$data = 'contacts[update][0][id]=2289365&contacts[update][0][name]=Имя+не+указано&contacts[update][0][responsible_user_id]=3876319&contacts[update][0][date_create]=1571496221&contacts[update][0][last_modified]=1571499023&contacts[update][0][created_user_id]=3876319&contacts[update][0][modified_user_id]=3876319&contacts[update][0][custom_fields][0][id]=101163&contacts[update][0][custom_fields][0][name]=Должность&contacts[update][0][custom_fields][0][values][0][value]=dfgdfs&contacts[update][0][custom_fields][0][code]=POSITION&contacts[update][0][custom_fields][1][id]=101165&contacts[update][0][custom_fields][1][name]=Телефон&contacts[update][0][custom_fields][1][values][0][value]=+72209211333&contacts[update][0][custom_fields][1][values][0][enum]=150989&contacts[update][0][custom_fields][1][code]=PHONE&contacts[update][0][old_responsible_user_id]=3876319&contacts[update][0][created_at]=1571496221&contacts[update][0][updated_at]=1571499023&contacts[update][0][type]=contact&account[subdomain]=waxijocod&account[id]=28666972&account[_links][self]=https://waxijocod.amocrm.ru';
parse_str($data, $result);
echo "JSON:".json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```